# Env variables showing as undefined when using browserify

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, environment-variables, browserify

I just installed browserify on my system and am able to bundle my scripts but when I call my env variables I am getting `undefined`.

My file structure:

```
MyProject
    dist
    node_modules
    src
        index.html
        index.js
        bundle.js
    .env
    package-lock.json
    package.json
    yarn.lock
```

index.html

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="record">
    <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-lg w-50">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rec-id" placeholder="Enter ID">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="mybtn" type="button">Enter</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center d-none" id="show-alert">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show row">
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
      <strong>Danger!</strong> Button was clicked
    </div>
  </div>


<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
console.log(process.env.MY_TOKEN);
```

Successfully ran `browserify src/index.js -o src/bundle.js`

.env

```
MY_TOKEN=qwer123456
```

When I run my code, I am getting `undefined` in my console instead of `qwer123456`.

Comment: Aren't environment variables used to store secrets on the server like a token? Why would these values be bundles on the client to run inside a browser?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, I need them to store auth tokens from for example slack and github

Comment: @nb_nb_nb — Is your goal just to keep the contents of the `.env` file out of your git repository or are you trying to keep them hidden from people using your website.

Comment: @Quentin, I am trying to do both

Comment: If the values make it to the browser then your secrets are no longer secrets

Comment: @Pointy, it doesn't, I only need use the token as of now to keep the file out of git. If code changes I might send it browser later.

Comment: @nb_nb_nb — The whole point of browserify is that it packages up the code to send to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

---

Webpack (which does a similar job to Browserify) has a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) that can expose dotenv data to bundled code. However, you **do not** want to do that.

You said, in a comment:

> > Is your goal just to keep the contents of the .env file out of your git repository or are you trying to keep them hidden from people using your website?

> I am trying to do both

A .env file serves two purposes:

- It makes it easy for you to use different values in different environments (e.g. the address of a database server when you have different databases for production, qa, development, and so on).
- It lets you avoid putting credentials into version control

It does not, and **cannot**, hide a value from the environment that needs to use it.

For your client-side JavaScript to access your Slack auth token, you have to give the Slack auth token to the browser. The browser is completely under the control of the user. If you do that then the user can read the auth token and do anything with the Slack API they like with that authorisation.

**To keep the tokens secret you need to use them in *server-side* code and expose any (limited) functionality the client should have over an API (e.g. one that can be accessed via Ajax) which you should probably secure with your own AuthN/AuthZ.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse content of the `.env` file by using `dotenv.parse()`:

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv'),
          fs = require('fs');

const buf = fs.readFileSync('./.env');
const envVars = dotenv.parse(buf);
console.log(envVars.MY_TOKEN);
```